# System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code on my `Site.Master` page:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">
    <li>
        <a href="<%=GetProfileLink()%>">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>My Profile
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="/Login.aspx?Logout=Y"><i class="icon-key"></i>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

The public method is as follows in the code-behind file:

```
public string GetProfileLink()
{
    string UserRoleID = Session["UserRoleID"].ToString();
    string ProfileLink = "#";
    if (UserRoleID == "2")
    {
        ProfileLink = "/User/AdminProfile.aspx";
    }
    else if (UserRoleID == "3")
    {
        ProfileLink = "/User/BranchProfile.aspx";
    }
    return ProfileLink;
}
```

This code has worked without issue for 3 years, now, when creating a new Web Form that has a DevExpress grid, this error is presenting itself. I've added a breakpoint in the `GetProfileLink()` and all values are present, the first if statement is true and once I click continue, the following error is shown within Visual Studio:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

What I don't understand is that the code works fine on every page, the correct profile link is displayed. When I browse to the new form, to test a cascading control, I find that the method returns the correct URL as a string (from the breakpoints) but then Visual Studio hangs for a few seconds and the exception is thrown. What's strange is that there is a similar method being called by the ASP page a few lines up and that doesn't have the same issue. I don't think an ASP Label would work for this, so what is the solution?

[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
[InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop() +6884317
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +84
   System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1405
```

I suspect that the conflict comes from this code on the ASP file:

```
    <div class="col-input">
        <dx:ASPxGridLookup ID="gl_UserType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ds_UserType" KeyFieldName="UTID" TextFormatString="{2}" ReadOnly="True">
            <GridViewProperties>
                <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="True"></SettingsBehavior>
            </GridViewProperties>
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UTID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="2" Visible="False">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UserType" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="User Type">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
            <DropDownButton Enabled="False">
            </DropDownButton>
            <FocusedStyle CssClass="form-control-focus">
            </FocusedStyle>
        </dx:ASPxGridLookup>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_UserType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Portal_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserTypeID] as UTID, UserType FROM [tbl_UserType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Corresponding code from the code-behind file is below:

```
protected void gl_EntityTypes_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxGridLookup gridLookup = sender as ASPxGridLookup;
    gridLookup.GridView.CustomCallback += new ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventHandler(gridView_CustomCallback);
}

public void gridView_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameters != "ValueChanged") return;

    ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
    var selectedValues = gl_UserType.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues(gl_UserType.KeyFieldName);
    if (selectedValues.Count == 0)
        selectedValues.Add(-1);
    CriteriaOperator selectionCriteria = new InOperator(gl_UserType.KeyFieldName, selectedValues);
}
```

Comment: Please add the Stack Trace here. Also try another session key, maybe DevExpress is messing with "UserRoleID".

Comment: Thanks @Delphi.Boy I think you’ve identified the problem, there’s a gridlookup that uses a KeyField name of “UserTypeId” - I’ll look into changing the keyfield name as this one appears to be conflicting with the application’s core

Comment: @Delphi.Boy I changed the KeyField name of the possibly conflicting code and it made no difference. Is there anything you can see from the stack trace that I've added?